# InsecurePlatformWarning while installing OpenSSL in python 2.7 (windows 8.1)

Tags: python, openssl

I have installed **pyOpenSSL** and all the required packages but i get this warning while installing OpenSSL .

```
$ pip install OpenSSL
Collecting OpenSSL
C:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSL
Context object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL conn
ections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarni
ng.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement OpenSSL (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for OpenSSL
```

I 've tried almost everything but still nothing.

Comment: i 've installed the requests but still getting the error

Answer (score 8):

It is pyOpenSSL, there is no `OpenSSL` package:

```
pip install pyOpenSSL
```

And `pip install requests[security]` should fix the warning

Comment: i ran the command and its allready satisfied . i think it should be work by now but i figured there was a problem with OpenSSL when i tried to run    >>> import OpenSSL
in python shell and got error

Comment: @Echidna, then it is installed already, what do you think `pip install OpenSSL` is going to install?

Comment: i am following the instructions of https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/twisted-network-programming/9781449326104/ch01.html   and i am here "If you’ve installed pyOpenSSL to use Twisted’s SSL features, you can test that that installation worked with:
`code
    >>> import OpenSSL
    >>> import twisted.internet.ssl
    >>> twisted.internet.ssl.SSL `

Comment: yes, you import it as `OpenSSL` but you install it as `pyOpenSSL`, are you saying you cannot import it?

Comment: i see , but then why i still getting error at import  when all stuff is installed .    `code ImportError: No module named OpenSSL `

Comment: What interpreter are you using? Also do you have your pythonpath setup properly in your environment variables?

Comment: i use Windows PowerShell with python command to run the import , i checked the path also , cant figure what's wrong

Comment: but is it python2 or 3?

Comment: well , its in python 2.7

Comment: Do you have python3 installed also?